# How to delete /var/folders/xx/xxxxxxxxx when the corresponding user account is deleted?

Tags: macos, user-account, sip

The user specified tmp path is `/var/folders/xx/xxxxxxxxx` , which can be got by `$TMPDIR`. It will be created when creating a new user.

But when I delete the user at System Preferences, choosing `Delete the home folder`, the tmp path isn't deleted automatically, even after a reboot.

The `/var/folders/xx/xxxx` path cannot be deleted manually. It cannot be deleted by `sudo rm -rf`, because it's protected by the System Integrity Protection(SIP).

```
$ sudo rm -rf /var/folders/hk
rm: /var/folders/hk/wq1w61c90wb1d0ycqwjy_6yh0000gq/0/com.apple.LaunchServices.dv: Operation not permitted
rm: /var/folders/hk/wq1w61c90wb1d0ycqwjy_6yh0000gq/0: Operation not permitted
rm: /var/folders/hk/wq1w61c90wb1d0ycqwjy_6yh0000gq/T: Operation not permitted
rm: /var/folders/hk/wq1w61c90wb1d0ycqwjy_6yh0000gq/C: Operation not permitted
rm: /var/folders/hk/wq1w61c90wb1d0ycqwjy_6yh0000gq: Operation not permitted
rm: /var/folders/hk: Operation not permitted
```

How can I delete it without turn off SIP?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there isnt a question asked

Comment: I had no problem running `cd /var/folders; sudo rm -r xx` for a deleted user. Does this not work in your case?

Comment: @nohillside Do you turn off System Integrity Protection?

Comment: Nope, SIP is turned on. And none of the folders in `/var/folders` (nor `/var/folders` itself) seem to be SIP protected here. Can you add the output of `ls -alO /var/folders` to the question?

Comment: Ah, also add the result of `ls -alO var/folders/hk/wq1w61c90wb1d0ycqwjy_6yh0000gq` and `ls -alO /var/folders/hk/wq1w61c90wb1d0ycqwjy_6yh0000gq/0/com.apple.LaunchServices.dv`.

Comment: @nohillside All have a `sunlnk` flag, and `sudo ls -alO /var/folders/hk/wq1w61c90wb1d0ycqwjy_6yh0000gq/0/com.apple.LaunchServices.dv` is Operation not permitted

Comment: SIP shows as `restricted`, not as `sunlnk` actually. And if I read the content of `/System/Library/Sandbox/rootless.conf` correctly, the actual content of `/private/var/folders` isn't part of SIP. Doesn't directly help you though.